# Header element embeds into navigation element

Tags: html, header, embed

I have no idea why the header is embedding into the navigation bar as they're different elements? Need the header underneath the navigation with no joy. Thanks in anticipation.
`Link:`https://jsfiddle.net/a6jxea0v

[image]

Comment: You have your nav element set at position fixed.  That removes it from relative positioning and fixes it at the top of the screen.  The header element is now the top remaining element in the document and it floats to the top of the screen (where it is hidden behind the header.)  You just need to work on the CSS.   If it were me, I'd just add a margin/padding  to the top of the relative positioned elements so content clears the nav element.  Another way to fix this is just remove `position: fixed;` from the nav element.

Comment: Thanks, zipzit! I had no idea that fixed position elements are removed from the document flow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `padding-top:45px;` to your header, because your navbar have fixed position so header start from the top of the body, so you need to add top spacing as per height of navbar.

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:45px 0 0;
    color: #000;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a6jxea0v/2/

Comment: Hi, Mukesh. Is there an additional way to put the navigation bar back to its original location (top of screen) and the header below it without using padding? Do you know the reason the header element is floating into the navigation?

Comment: Because you have fixed navbar, so header start at the top position of the body and it hide below the navbar

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped :)